# Add List objects from a single list to a new List using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

i've a list collection which looks like

```
myList[0].innerList[0 to 50]
myList[1].innerList[51  to 100]
myList[2].innerList[101 to 120]
```

the myList can go as per the size, at max there are 50 objects in the innerList. I get the innerList as a response from an API where the page size is set to 50.

i want my new list to have all these 0 - 120 objects in a single list like

```
newList[0 to 120]
```

i'm trying using LINQ like this

```
var newList = from reg in myList
           select reg.innerList.ToList();
```

But i get

```
newList[0].[0 to 50]
newList[1].[51 to 100]
```

Can anyone help me with the LINQ ?

Comment: you want to copy the items of one list to second list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

think [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should do the trick.

```
var newList = myList.SelectMany(x => x.innerList);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are nearly there

```
var newList = (from reg in myList      // for each inner list
               from range in reg       // for each item in each inner list
               select range).ToList();
```

Comment: This too works Ondrej Janacek. Thanks! The selectMany property achieves this in a single line. Hence i'm marking that as an answer.

Comment: @Raza I completely understand. I posted the answer just because I felt that it would be beneficial for you to see the query syntax as well (the other one is called lambda syntax). So just for the sense of completeness.

Comment: Thank you Ondrej Janacek. Yes your code actually helped me visualize the query syntax. :)